# Can't fill lightning input rich text with email template body LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, email-template

I'm developing an LWC which sends an email on a case detail page. The subject and the body of the email is automatically filled by subject and description of the case. I want also to be able to concatenate an email template body to the current body but it doesn't work. Can you please help ?

Here a screenshot of the component with description and body filled at the start :

[image]

The view of the component :

```
<div class="slds-form form slds-var-p-top_small">
                <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal slds-form-element_1-col">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="to">To</label>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <c-email-input onselection={handleToAddressChange}></c-email-input>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal slds-form-element_1-col">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="cc">Cc</label>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <c-email-input onselection={handleCcAddressChange}></c-email-input>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <lightning-combobox
                        name="from"
                        label="From"
                        value={from}
                        placeholder="Select Template"
                        options={fromOptions}
                        onchange={handleFromChange} ></lightning-combobox>

                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="subject">Subject : </label>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="subject"
                            id="subject"
                            value={sujet}
                            placeholder="Subject..."
                            class="slds-input"
                            onchange={handleSubjectChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-var-p-top_small">
                        <lightning-input-rich-text value={description} onchange={handleBodyChange}></lightning-input-rich-text>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--<div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal slds-form-element_1-col">
                <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="Templates">Templates</label>
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">-->
                    <lightning-combobox
                        name="templates"
                        label="Templates"
                        value={templateValue}
                        placeholder="Select Template"
                        options={templatesNames}
                        onchange={handleTemplateChange} ></lightning-combobox>
                <!--</div>
            </div>-->
        </div>
```

And finally the js :

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from "lwc";
import { getRecord, getFieldValue  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import sendEmailController from "@salesforce/apex/EmailClass.sendEmailController";
import getEmailTemplates from "@salesforce/apex/EmailClass.getEmailTemplates";
import getEmailToCaseAddresses from "@salesforce/apex/EmailClass.getEmailToCaseAddresses";
import NUMBER_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.CaseNumber';
import DESCRIPTION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Description';
import SUBJECT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Subject';
import WEBEMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.SuppliedEmail';


export default class EmailLwc extends LightningElement {
    toAddress = [];
    ccAddress = [];
    subject = "";
    body = "";
    requestNumber = "";
    wantToUploadFile = false;
    noEmailError = false;
    invalidEmails = false;
    fromOptions = [];

    @track templateValue;
    @track files = [];
    @track templates = [];
    @track templatesNames = [];
    @track fromAdresses = [];

    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [NUMBER_FIELD,DESCRIPTION_FIELD,SUBJECT_FIELD,WEBEMAIL_FIELD] })case;

    @wire(getEmailTemplates)
    wiredOptions({data,error}) {
        if(data){
                this.templates = data;
                for(const elt of data){
                    const option = {label:elt.Name,value: elt.Name};
                    this.templatesNames = [...this.templatesNames, option];
                }
        }
        if(error){
            console.log("errrrrrrror");
            this.error = error;
        }
                
    }

    get number() {
        this.requestNumber = getFieldValue(this.case.data, NUMBER_FIELD);
        return this.requestNumber;
    }

    get sujet() {
        this.subject = getFieldValue(this.case.data, SUBJECT_FIELD);
        return this.subject;
        
    }

    set description(desc){
        this.body += desc;
    }

    get description() {
        this.body = getFieldValue(this.case.data, DESCRIPTION_FIELD);
        return this.body;
    }

    get webemail() {
        return getFieldValue(this.case.data, WEBEMAIL_FIELD);
    }

    handleTemplateChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
        const templateSelected = this.templates.find(element => element.Name == this.value);
        console.log('templateSelected ',templateSelected.Body);
        this.description = '<br/>'+templateSelected.Body;
    }
```